# Adding String array to JSON

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am building a graphics diagram from JSON. This is how my current method looks like:

```
  loadGraph(objectName, objectCol1){
    this.graph.fromJSON({
      "cells": [{
        "question": objectName,
        "options": [{"id": "yes", "text": "Yes"}, {"id": "no", "text": "No"}]
      }
      ]
    });
  }
```

However, instead of hardcoding the options values, I am trying to pass the 'objectCol1' in it. So it should look like this:

```
  loadGraph(objectName, objectCol1){
    this.graph.fromJSON({
      "cells": [{
        "question": objectName,
        "options": [objectCol1]
      }
      ]
    });
  }
```

Now the problem comes when I want to add my String array as value of 'options' key. As you can see, my array is formed to look like JSON.

```
let arr1: String[] = [];
for (let entry of this.dropdownData.columns) {
  arr1.push('{"id": "'+entry.name+'", "text": "'+entry.name+'"}');
}

this.edit.loadGraph(objectName, objectName2,arr1.toString());
```

arr1.toString() returns data enclosed with quotation marks, therefore my JSON is not good. "options" value looks like:

```
"options": ['{"id": "ID", "text": "ID"},{"id": "CREATED_BY", "text": "CREATED_BY"}']
```

The data obtained from array should be without '' marks. What's your suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not the `'`s around your JSON. It is invalid JSON to start with. Valid JSON has to have a top level Object, or Array. Read [json.org](http://json.org)

Also, you don't need to push a string to the array, or pass the `arr1.toString()` to the function.

If the loadGraph function is using JSON.parse, then you can use something like

```
arr1.push( JSON.stringify( {id: entry.name, text: entry.name } )
```

And pass the whole array instead of passing `arr1.toString()`.

In the loadGraph method you can then just do

```
this.graph.fromJSON({
  "cells": [{
    "question": objectName,
    "options": objectCol1
  }]
});
```

and it should work.

If the loadGraph function is not using JSON.parse, you wouldn't need to wrap the objects in JSON.stringify as well. This does not seem to be case, however.

Comment: This returns {id: id1, text: id1 }, {id: id2, text: id2 }, ...   The return should be wrapped in [ ] brackets to look like.[ {id: id1, text: id1 }, {id: id2, text: id2 }, ...]

Comment: I wrapped the return in [ ] brackets. When I log it, it is perfectly fine. Just how it should be. But the problem is my graph is not loading properly. But when I copy the returned JSON and paste it on 'objectCol1' it works fine. Any clues?

Comment: Are you passing the whole array or `arr1.toString()`? There should not be any issue if you are passing `arr1` as an argument.

Comment: I am passing the whole array. I think that the problem is that my array is type of String. Therefore every element of my array is returned like: "{"id":"ID","text":"ID"}"     .. I don't want to enclose it with quotes.

Comment: The return should be array of JSON Objects

Comment: Can you try once without JSON.stringify? There is no ideal way to strip the outside `"`s, because the end result will be a string itself. However, since JSON.parse should have worked with the result of JSON.stringify, I suspect the library is not using JSON.parse. So you should get rid od JSON.stringify in your code as well.

Comment: I fixed it. The problem was in fact in String array type. I changed let arr1: String[ ] = [ ];   to  let arr1: any[ ] = [ ];    But thanks for your help though

Answer (score 0):

Data is enclosed in quotation marks because you wrote them that way. Try this instead and look for the difference.

```
let arr1: String[] = [];
for (let entry of this.dropdownData.columns) {
  arr1.push({id: entry.name, text: entry.name});
}

this.edit.loadGraph(objectName, objectName2,arr1.toString());
```